# Forgot to put a slash before download path, where were these files downloaded to?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, directory, download

I forgot to put a slash before my `home` folder when downloading some files and it seems that they downloaded successfully but I can't seem to navigate before `/` within my thunar explorer so I can't get to them. My hard drive appears to have less space on it from these files being downloaded. So where did these files go exactly?

Comment: What was the exact command you ran?

Comment: how can we possibly know what you did unless you tell us

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't specify a `/` at the beginning of a path (**absolute** path), it becomes a **relative** path.

As such, it is relative to the current directory on which you are.

So for instance, when downloading a file, if you specify as destination `home/anon/foo/bar.txt` and you are in `/tmp`, the file is not downloaded as `/home/anon/foo/bar.txt` (in you homedir) but is going to be downloaded to `/tmp/home/anon/foo/bar.txt`. Whether this will be successfully or not depends whether the path already exists or the command you used is allowed to create the destination directory path.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your system to list files that have recently been created/modified.

For example, in the last 24 hours (one full day)

```
find / -type f -mtime -1
```

Or in the last 60 minutes (GNU extension; not standard)

```
find / -type f -mmin -60
```

More details either here on https://unix.stackexchange.com or with `man find`.